# How to set foreground color optionally to View in swiftUI using ViewModifier

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have an image view, based on a boolean value i should use tint, if condition is true i should use tint else I should use the original image, I tried in many way using ViewModifier but I can't find the solution. Is that possible to get the expected result using ViewModifier?

```
struct ViewColor: ViewModifier {
    var tint: Bool
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        Group {
            if self.tint {
                content.foregroundColor(Color("colorText"))
            }else
            {
              //  content.foregroundColor(Color("colorAccent"))
    
            }
        }
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution (tested with Xcode 12b)

```
struct ViewColor: ViewModifier {
    var tint: Bool

    @ViewBuilder
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if self.tint {
            content.foregroundColor(Color("colorText"))
        } else {
            content
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is working, I used image inside button. I added .renderingMode(.original) then it worked

Comment: I added my answer as well

Answer (score 0):

I used image inside the button.
To maintain image original color inside Button we should use `renderingMode(.original)` to tint the image we should use`renderingMode(. template)`, For my scenario I should use conditional operator to get the exact result, Here is the code

```
 struct ButtonIconView: View {
    var icon : String
    var tint : Bool = true
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            print("Button action")
            
        }){
            Image(icon)
                .renderingMode(self.tint ? .template : .original) // To get the original image color we should use .original in rendering mode to tint image we should use .template
                .resizable().scaledToFit() .modifier(ViewColor(tint: self.tint)).frame(width: 18, height: 18)
        }.frame(width: 54, height:48)
    }
}
```

To add and remove tint color using `ViewModifier` we should follow the [@Asperi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62620032/3615605) answer

```
struct ViewColor: ViewModifier {
    var tint: Bool

    @ViewBuilder
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if self.tint {
            content.foregroundColor(Color("colorText"))
        } else {
            content
        }
    }
}
```